# Google Maps APIs sometimes requires domain verification?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I maintain a WordPress store locator plugin, and this week someone told me it wasn't working anymore. Eventually he fixed it by verifying his domain in the API Console.

That this was a solution to some APIs of Google Maps not working was new to me, and it's also the first time someone told me they fixed it this way.

The problem is that I can't find any information in which scenario verifying your domain fixes a Google Maps API related problem. I read through the Geocode API / Google Maps JavaScript API / Google Places API Web Service pages, but no where do I see something about the need to verify your domain ( I could of course have missed it ).

Does anyone know when you need to verify your domain if you want to use the Google Maps APIs? Normally it works fine without doing it, but in his case it wasn't, and I really like to know what he could possible have done to make it a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to verify the domain for using Google Maps API.

You need to generate one API Key for your app so you can use it when you call the Google Map JavaScript API like this:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

Substitute the value `YOUR_API_KEY` for the one that Google generated for you.